# Pasting string from one cell to another after a unique word

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This code I am using is only allowing me to past the range of the source range at the end of the string not after the uniqueString. Is there a way I can paste the source range after the unique string in the target range ?

```
function copyData() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet110");
 var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange("A3:A8");
 var targetRange = sourceSheet.getRange("B3:B8");
 var uniqueString = "Critical dates meeting comments:\n";
 var sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();
 var targetValues = targetRange.getValues();
 for (var i = 0; i < sourceValues.length; i++){
 targetValues[i][0] = targetValues[i][0] + sourceValues[i][0]; 
}
 targetRange.setValues(targetValues);
}
```

[Test](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kLu-spaB_yWU2t-aPnITllfsSNApJ82jJ-ekOaM3sCs/edit?usp=sharing)

Sheet link "Test" above. I want to transfer the strings from column A to Column B and paste them after this unique string "Critical dates meeting comments:".

Currently the code pastes the string at the end of the cell as you will notice "Feb'23..." comments where it is located.

The result I want is:

"Critical dates meeting comments:

Feb'23 Decision forthcoming ------ the string is from cell A3

Dec'22 intention to renew

etc,,"

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect?

Comment: i mistakenly added my response on the answer below. please have a look

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `i mistakenly added my response on the answer below.`, in this case, please add it to your question, and remove your answer. And, unfortunately, I cannot see your sample Spreadsheet.

Comment: i edited my question and included the link (Test) to the sheet and added more information to make it clearer